# Java method to replace a letter with another

Tags: java

I need help to do my exercises. I want to replace letters ‘a’ with an ‘e’ in a phrase. For the input: `"are you angry"` the output should be: `"ere you engry"`.
I tried this but I can't fix it.

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    String s= "are you angry";
    remplaceLettre(s);

}
public static void remplaceLettre(String s){
    char converted = 0;
    String w = "e";
       
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) =='a') {
            converted = Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i));
            w = s.replace(s.charAt(i), converted);
            s = w;
                
        } else {
            converted = Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i));
            w = s.replace(s.charAt(i), converted);
            s = w;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

}

```
   output : "are you angry"

   Expected output : "ere you engry"
```

Comment: What output do you get?  How does what you get differ from what you expected?

Comment: The output of this is not "are you angry" but rather "ARE YOU ANGRY". At no point to you attempt to replace 'a' with 'e', which can simply be done with String::replace.

Answer (score 2):

You can use String.replace method like this:

```
public static void remplaceLettre(String s){
   System.out.println(s.replace("a", "e"));
}
```

If you must use case insensitive replace try this:

```
s.replaceAll("(?i)a", "e")
```

Comment: `String::replace` takes either chars, or CharSequences (typically, Strings) which it interprets literally. It does not support regular expressions.

Comment: @DavidConrad you right. It is typo. Should be s.replaceAll("(?i)a", "e")

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.khan.vaquar;

    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String str = "are you angry";
            char replaceWith = 'e';
            int index[] = { 0, 8 }; //here you can add index want to replace
            replaceLettre(str, replaceWith, index);

        }

        public static String replaceLettre(String str, char ch, int[] index) {
            if (null == str) {
                return str;
            }

            char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {
                chars[index[i]] = ch;
            }
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(chars));
            return String.valueOf(chars);
        }

    }
```

Output :  ere you engry

Comment: Do you think this will replace all 'a's with 'e's?

Comment: Please run and see results "ere you angry"

Comment: wil replace on index , if want to replace all then replace all will work but as i am looking her code she is addling logic so may be not interested on replace all

Comment: take a look now